# Why does Apple Pay show up on my device but not when Apple Connect tests my app?

Tags: ios, applepay

When uploading up app build for App Store approval by Apple, I keep getting the following rejection note:

> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed

> We're looking forward to completing our review of your app, but we need more information to continue. Specifically, we noticed that your binary includes the PassKit framework for implementing Apple Pay, but we were unable to verify any integration of Apple Pay within your app.

> Apple Pay is a mobile payment technology that provides an easy and secure way for users to pay for physical goods and real-world services in apps and on the web.

I left them a note of where Apple Pay is used in the app, but apparently they don't see it on their end. Does anyone know why this issue would arise? I honestly am not sure where to even start.

[I followed this documentation strictly](https://docs.stripe.com/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=ios&mobile-ui=payment-element#apple-pay)

Here is what they see:

[image: Here is what they see]

Here is what I see:

[image: Here is what I see]

Comment: You need to look at your code - are there any conditions that are checked before you show the Apple Pay button? Is it possible that the reviewer doesn't meet those conditions?